# Balancing precision and recall in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

When designing a neural network, are there architectures that can be used to favor precision vs. recall and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use ROC curve to find the optimal point, you can change the output threshold and get TP Rate , FP rate and plot ROC curve.

From ROC curve, you can get the optimal threshold value, to have the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

If we are doing classification task, using weighted loss function (imbalanced loss on false positive and false negative) is one solution.

In addition, if model produce probability on two classes, changing the decision threshold would also help.

Answer (score -1):

I found some blog posts with good links:

http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

https://www.quora.com/In-classification-how-do-you-handle-an-unbalanced-training-set

Still experimenting with what will work for my dataset.

Comment: Downvoting because both of those articles lack nuance. The correct procedure in most situations is to fit a probability model, and intellegently threshold the predictions.